# How can i call a Func<int,int,int> arguments in a method in C#?

Tags: c#, func, actionmethod

I am trying to create a method which accepts different methods(`Func`s) as a parameter.
I have a small problem in defining the `Func`s arguments. 
Suppose i need to call some thing like this :

```
public static void SomeTestMethod(int number,string str)
{
    Check(MethodOne(number,str));
}
```

And For Check i have this:

```
public static int Check(Func<int,string,int> method)
{
         // some conditions 
      method(where should i get the arguments ?);
}
```

Now my question is how should i set the needed arguments? I feel providing separate arguments for Check, is not elegant, since i need to call Check with the signature i provided in the TestMethod.
I dont want to have

```
Check(MethodOne,arg1,arg2,etc));
```

If it is possible i need to provide  this signature instead:

```
Check(MethodOne(number,str));
```

Comment: It's *very* unclear what you're asking. If that even compiles, then `MethodOne` returns a `Func<int, string>`. It would really help if you'd provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem - and explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: how are we supposed to know?

Comment: Just note that `Func<int,string>` takes just one parameter (an int) and returns a `string`. You invoke it like so `var result = method(someInt);` - presumably `Check` should then reason over `result`, or return it?

Comment: @StuartLC: missed that, corrected the question.

Comment: After the edit, you would need lambda functions, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* you want this:

```
public static void SomeTestMethod(int number,string str)
{
    Check( () => MethodOne(number,str));
}

public static int Check(Func<int> method)
{
         // some conditions 
      return method();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about lambdas :) , thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void Check<TReturnValue>(
                       Func<int, string, TReturnValue> method, 
                       int arg1, 
                       string arg2)
{
    method(arg1, arg2);
}
```

calling:

```
public static SomeClass MethodOne(int p1, string p2)
{
   // some body
}

Check(MethodOne, 20, "MyStr");
```

You have missed the type of return value (the last generic parameter means the type of return value). If you don't want to `Func` return anything, just use `Action`:

```
public static void Check(
                       Action<int, string> method, 
                       int arg1, 
                       string arg2)
{
    method(arg1, arg2);
}
```